# Coding style - call method on a pointer after NULL check inside if condition

Tags: c++, if-statement, coding-style

Say we have two pointers to objects that can contain a property equal and we want to check it. But first, we need to check whether the pointers are initialized or not.
What option is usually preferred? will it have some micro impact on performance?

```
if(p1 && p2 && p1->getA() == p2->getB()){
    execute fancy code
}
```

or:

```
if(p1 && p2){
    if(p1->getA() == p2->getB()){
        execute fancy code
    }
}
```

I was wondering what is usual preferred.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, `if (ptr)` doesn't check whether a pointer is intialised or not, it checks if it isn't NULL. You can initialize a pointer to NULL and the condition wouldn't hold.

Second, there are two cases to be treated:

**1) the pointers are allowed by the code logic to be `NULL`**

In this case, you most certainly want different behavior for the two cases. So what would be appropriate is:

```
if ( ptr )
{  
   ptr->foo();
   //...
}
else
{
   //...
}
```

The second syntax doesn't make much sense semantically `if ( ptr && ptr->foo() )` implies that you want to be sure `ptr` isn't NULL before calling `foo()`, instead of grouping the logic bound to the case where `foo` isn't `false` into a use-case.

**2) the pointers aren't allowed to be `NULL`**

If they're not allowed to be `NULL`, then you should deal with the case that they are `NULL`, not by excluding it completely, which is what

```
if ( ptr && ptr->foo() )
```

does. But by making it burn:

```
if ( !ptr )
    throw std::exception("WTF! This shouldn't be NULL");
```

`ptr && ptr->foo()` seems like it's meant to prevent crashes, but at the same time hide bugs. In a clean logic, you wouldn't need to check for `NULL`. If the object wasn't created and the pointer didn't point to anything meaningful, you'd have a bug regardless of whether you call `foo` or not, so you should deal with it, not hide it behind a check.

Comment: It could be loose use of the word 'initialised', but making a pointer NULL when the object doesn't exist is very common, and indeed good practice.

Comment: That's my point. He probably said initialised when he meant 'not NULL'.

Comment: You are right, what I mean was if the object which the pointer "points" is created.

Comment: @MarioA.CorcheroJiménez ok. I edited my answer because, to me, it seems that the issue is more complex than simply having an opinion. It seems to be more logic-related than a coding-style question.

Comment: you should not check if a pointer is 'NULL' you check if it is 'null_ptr'

Comment: @thecoshman: if you mean the C++11 thing then it's called `nullptr` rather than `null_ptr`, which suggests you aren't using it much either ;-p In English, to be precise one should say "check whether the pointer is null" (or "is a null pointer") rather than "check whether the pointer is NULL". In C++ a pointer *isn't* ever NULL, because NULL is not a pointer. A pointer can compare equal to NULL, though, in which case it is a null pointer.

Comment: @SteveJessop I use which ever one highlights in a pleasing colour :P

Comment: @SteveJessop oh, so now you are throwing English at me? (╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻

Answer (score 3):

Performance - no difference. The compiler will almost certainly produce the same code in each case.

Personally, I prefer the former as being more idiomatic. You *very* often see code like this in C/C++:

```
if (ptr && *ptr == x)
```

and what you've written is just a small extension of this.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer the second one for legibility and maintenance purposes:

```
// First thing is to check the pointers
if(p1 && p2){
    // Second thing is call the getters.
    if(p1->getA() == p2->getB()){
        // execute fancy code
    }
}
```

While I'm debugging, is pretty bothersome to be stuck into a line with too many conditions because it's not clear wich condition makes the whole thing to be `true` or `false` without checking each sub-condition at once. But when each related condition are in separated `if`s it's clearer, easier to understand, easier to debug and not very bloat.

But, if I'm forced to use the first one (sometimes you're forced to use some coding styles) I will use parenthesis to emphasize the two parts of the expression:

```
// Look: FIRST check the pointers and...
// and THEN call the getters.
if ( (p1 && p2) && (p1->getA() == p2->getB()) ){
    // execute fancy code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer `if((p1 != NULL) && (p2 != NULL) && (p1->getA() == p2->getB())){ }`. using parenthesis makes the code straight-forward and eliminates "guessing" the precedence. Being EXPLICIT than IMPLICIT is the way to go. Any decent production-grade compiler generates same code for both if() statements.